# Clean solution in Visual Studio 2008 build event

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, scripting

I'm looking for a way to clean my solution as well as stop the localhost development server with each build in VS2008. Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

edit: I apologize for not being clear. I am wanting to include this in a build event so that I don't have to manually do each task with each rebuild. Also, a call to clear the cached files in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use Build->Clean Solution?

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221803/visual-studio-2008-clean-solution-option) that discusses about this.

By using Clean Solution all the files are cleared. And by using Rebuild Solution all the files inside your bin folder are cleared, and new files generated.

Answer (score 0):

Build -> Rebuild solution (clean + Build )

```
     or
```

Build -> Clean Solution