# Build does not release the new changes on Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am a part of TFS project. We use Visual Studio 2005. It was allright some days ago, I mean I used to be able to build a project with new changes. 
However, today!

For instance, I have a page under a web application. I add two text box component and I build the whole project but it does not build the project with two new text boxes. It all says "build succeded" but unfotunately without the new changes.

How can I configure the Visual Studio to do the excat job, I mean the right build operation.

Regards
bk

**One more information about this question which has an importance for me to keep working faster like before:
So ;**

- One of my collegue from the team that we work  together said that: apperantely  the build order has changed when someone has added a new project to the common solution that I want to build-up. 
  Any idea to roll-back the configuration or whatever ? since I fed-up doing firstly clean the solution then build the solution to let Visual Studio consider the new changes that I made...

Comment: -The folder is writeble.
-I found a solution for this problem. I click "Clean Solution" before doing build operation. 

So now the question is, how can I build a healty build operation without clicking "Clean Solution".

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was because of the references each other of several pages. We created a dummy web service to bridge the web services between all necessary methods

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the build configuration? You can set it to ignore certain projects within the solution.

If it is set, then check the folder where the assemblies will go are all writable.

Another option is to set the build ouput to verbose and see exatcly what is getting built? Can you see your new project getting built?

Could there be a referencing issue - are you building OK but running an old component?

Comment: -The folder is writeble. -I found a solution for this problem. I click "Clean Solution" before doing build operation. So now the question is, how can I build a healty build operation without clicking "Clean Solution". Regards –

Comment: Hi, you don't normally need to "Clean Solution".
If you find that you have to keep "Cleaning" then there is still an underlying problem. Google what the clean does (it's quite simple) and step through to see bit of the clean is actually fixing your issue.

Regards,

Jim

Comment: Jim, thanks for your advice. I still google it but nothing happend for the underlined problem.
hope to get an idea soon, since always doing clean before build is quite boring for me. :(

Regards
Bilgin

Comment: No problem - did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221803/visual-studio-2008-clean-solution-option

Comment: the problem was because of the references each other of several pages. We created a dummy web service to bridge the web services between all necessary methods.