# C# why empty src folders are copied to the debug and release directory after build?

Tags: c#, .net

We are using Visual Studio 2008 professional. We have created an entity data model in our src\systeminfo folder. Since then our release and debug folder have a empty src\systeminfo folder. we don't need them. how to stop VS to create that empty folder structure? thanks

EDIT:

current directory tree:

```
project\Properties
project\References
project\src
project\src\common
.
.
project\src\systeminfo
project\src\util
project\App.config
project\Settings.cs
```

Comment: Can you show us where this folder is in the Solution tree?

Comment: refer to the EDIT section please

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to dig through the msbuild .target files to find out what build rule creates this folder.  You might get a hint from looking at the build log if you switch it to diagnostic.  Tools + Options, Project and Solutions, Build and Run.

A more pragmatic approach would be to just delete the folders in a post build event.  Like:

```
if exist "$(TargetDir)src\systeminfo" rmdir "$(TargetDir)src\systeminfo"
if exist "$(TargetDir)src" rmdir "$(TargetDir)src"
```

Even more pragmatic is to not worry about it...

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to 'Copy to Output Directory' on the properties window.
Set it to 'Do not copy' for these folders

Comment: checked before the question, no that option for folders

Comment: You have to select a file,NOT the folder for this option to appear.

Comment: my issue is those empty folders

Comment: All files inside that folder are NOT TO COPY

Comment: I'd say try 'Clean' build and see if the empty folders were not created a long while ago. Pls check out this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221803/visual-studio-2008-clean-solution-option