# Clean solution before debugging in Visual Studio with SQLCE

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm creating a C# WPF app with SQLCE. Each time before I debug, I have to run "clean solution" or it will throws out a XmlParseException. Why? What is clean solution - is there some sort of caching in SQLCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it has anything with SQLCE. Clean Solution - deletes all the compiled and temporary files associated with a solution. It ensures that the next build is a full one, rather than only changed files being recompiled. You can get more info in the SO link [What is clean solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221803/visual-studio-2008-clean-solution-option)