# Can additional file types be added to Visual Studios clean procedure?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, build

According to one of the answers in to [Visual Studio (2008) 'Clean Solution' Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221803/visual-studio-2008-clean-solution-option), the visual studio clean command deletes files of the following types:

> *.obj - object code
>
> *.pdb - program debug databse file
>
> *.bsc - source browser database
>
> *.ilk - incremental linker file
>
> *.sbr - source browser intermediate file
>
> *.idb - rebuild dependency file
>
> *.lib - library file
>
> *.exe - executable

Can additional file types be added to this list manually, and in that case how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++ projects under 2012, 2010 and 2008 (non-express versions), bring up the project properties dialog (right click the project in the solution view and select 'Properties') and look under the 'General' section... you'll see a property called "Extensions to Delete on Clean". You can add your own choices in there.

I don't have the express versions to hand to see if the option is available there too, but I'd be surprised if it weren't.